# python regex expression image format

Tags: python, regex, image, format, expression

I want to limit formatting.

- The length is 20
- the name does not contain special characters. like *,'%$^&.@#!~
- The image format is jpg, jpeg, png, gif, bmp, and webp

so i tried, I wrote it as below. However, I don't know to exclude special symbols.
Help me bro!

> '^(?!.{20}).*\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|webp)$'

Comment: Safer to specify which symbol you want to allow.  In Perl, I'd use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{20}\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|webp)\z/` (assuming you're not including the extension in the length).

Comment: When tested, the results are all wrong. Am I testing it wrong at regexr.com?

Comment: regexr.com doesn't do Perl, but PCRE is close enough. I have no idea what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only file name to be with length between 1 and 19 (less then 20 without include extension) :

```
^(?:\w|\s|\d){1,19}\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|webp)$
```

else

```
^(?=(?:\w|\s|\d)+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|webp)).{1,19}$
```

Comment: Why aren't they showing up as 'Tests' when tested on the https://regexr.com/ site?

Comment: When tested, the results are all wrong.

Comment: test for [regex1](https://regexr.com/6aevr) , [regex2](https://regexr.com/6aevu) and if you have multiline to test u need to add multiline flag

Comment: I wrote it wrong because I am not good at English. I want to make it less than 20 letters.

Comment: And is this the essential way to enter space?

Comment: @GH00N i changed my answer to fit your need

Comment: thx bro i will use it

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude what you want to allow to match using a negated character class, and repeat that 1-19 times if you want to make it less than 20 characters.

```
^[^*,'%$^&.@#!~\r\n]{1,19}\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|webp)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXqxL1/1)